# Set OnClickListener for custom View dynamically

Tags: android, events

I add my custom `View`'s dynamically but I don't know how to set click listeners for them.

My code:

```
rect1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            frame_view.addView(new CustomView(getApplicationContext())
            .setOnLongClickListener(listener);
        }
    });
```

rect1 = my button.

Eclipse underlines `addView` and shows this error:

> The method addView(View) in the type ViewGroup is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CustomView objCustomView=new CustomView(getApplicationContext());   
objCustomView.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
frame_view.addView(objCustomView)
```

Comment: using `ViewGroup` allows to set click lisnener in method `addView`?